# Why jest is not able to find data-testid in map function in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Below is a piece of code over which testing seem not to work. However if I explicitely put data-testid = 'w_1' (not dynamically ofcourse) in a separate deletable div, then its working fine. What's the mistake in it?

```
export default class App extends Component {
  clickTest(){
     alert('hi');

}
  render() {
    const vehicles = ['Maruti', 'BMW', 'Renault']

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="heading">Online Car Rental Service</h1>

        <div className="container">
        

          {vehicles.map((item, index) =>
            <div className="card" data-testid={('w_'+index)} onClick={this.clickTest.bind(this)}>
              {item}
            </div>
          )}}
```

jest code:

```
test('test click on map', async () => {

  render(<App />);

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('w_1'))

});
```

Error:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="w_1"]
```

Comment: Have you looked at what *does* get rendered?

Answer (score 1):

`getByTestId()` only returns the first data-testid.

If you need to select multiple `data-testid` with the same testid you have to use `getAllByTestId()` that returns an Array with all the elements who own the same `data-testid`.

So you do not need to dynamically assign a testid as you did with the index in your `map()`.